# Linq to entities - searching in EntityCollection navigation properties

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

We have classes

```
public Invoice: EntityObject
{
    public EntityCollection<InvoicePosition> Positions { get {...}; set{...}; }
    ...
}

public InvoicePosition: EntityObject
{
    public string GroupName { get {...}; set{...}; }
}
```

We are given `IQueryable<Invoice>`, we are not given `IQueryable<InvoicePosition>`. How should I find invoices that have positions, where GroupName is 'Fuel'?

```
IQueryable<Invoice> invoices = InvoiceRepository.List();
IQueryable<Invoice> invoicesThatHaveFuelPositions = 
    from i in invoices
    where ?
    select i
```

EntityFramework should be able to translate it to proper sql query.

**EDIT**

As Mark Seemann wrote, I can use:

```
IQueryable<Invoice> invoices = InvoiceRepository.List().Include("Positions").Include("OtherInclude");
IQueryable<Invoice> invoicesThatHaveFuelPositions = 
    from i in invoices
    from p in i.Positions
    where p.GroupName = 'Fuel'
    select i;
```

There is a problem. When I use this filtering, I lose "OtherInclude". I think that this is not proper way of filtering when using EF. I'll have to change it to:

```
IQueryable<Invoice> invoices = InvoiceRepository.List().Include("Positions").Include("OtherInclude");
IQueryable<Invoice> invoicesThatHaveFuelPositions = invoices.Where(???);
```

But what should I write in Where?

**EDIT**

Changed Include("Position") to Include("Positions").

**EDIT**

Alex James gave link to the tip (http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx), which suggests:

```
IQueryable<Invoice> invoicesThatHaveFuelPositions = 
    from i in invoices
    where i.Positions.Any(p => p.GroupName == 'Fuel')
    select i;
```

It seems to work and doesn't influence EF includes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on Marks answer. If you do this:

```
var q = from i in invoices.Include("something")
        from p in i.Positions
        where p.GroupName == "Fuel"
        select i;
```

The include is lost (see [this tip](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx)) because the EF loses all includes if the shape of the query changes, for example if you do implicit joins like in a SelectMany query, aka from from.

The workaround is to write your query, and then at the end apply the Include.

Something like this:

```
var q = ((from i in invoices
        from p in i.Positions
        where p.GroupName == "Fuel"
        select i) as ObjectQuery<Invoice>).Include("something");
```

If you do this the Entity Framework actually does the include.

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Adding Include in the end is problematic, because I use repository pattern and Includes are applied first. The middle solution (using Any()) fits me.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ought to work:

```
var q = from i in invoices
        from p in i.Positions
        where p.GroupName == "Fuel"
        select i;
```

However, that uses the navigation property `Positions`, which by default isn't loaded (the Entity Framework uses explicit loading). It will, however, work, if the `invoices` variable was created like this:

```
var invoices = from i in myObjectContext.Invoices.Include("Positions")
               select i;
```

Comment: Invoice.Positions is EntityCollection. It doesn't have GroupName property. It has list of InvoicePosition.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the code in the question. I just updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, now it compiles, but doesn't work well with EF. I had Include("Positions") when taking from repository, but I had other includes too and they are lost during that operation.

Comment: You should be able to chain calls to Include together, and they should all stay populated on the object after the query. I need more information to be able to tell you why the other Includes are lost.

Comment: What information? I see in Profiler that EF construct other query and it doesn't contain defined Includes.

Comment: When I use your solution, profiler shows simple query that contains joining Invoices and InvoicePositions tables and selects only properties of Invoice.

Comment: I saw your question update, and you wrote "Position" and not "Positions" - I don't know if that's just a typo? IIRC, the string passed to the Include method must be the exact name of the Navigation Property.

Comment: I am sorry, that was just a typo.